# Get outline for NSGlyph

Tags: c++, cocoa

With Core Text it was possible to get the outline of a CGGlyph by `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(...)`. Now I'd like to port from Core Text to Cocoa's font engine, so the question is:
**Is there a way to get the outline for a NSGlyph?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `NSBezierPath`'s [`-appendBezierPathWithGlyph:inFont:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000339-CHDCEDFI).

I'd like to add that you can use CoreText with Cocoa, too. So in that sense you don't have to port at all.

Comment: Thanks! I want this for a c++ graphics framework. Previously I was using Core Text, but I thought, using Cocoa would be more modern ...

Comment: Core Text was introduced in Leopard, so it isn't old. It's largely just the Cocoa text-drawing APIs ported to Core Foundation. Some classes, such as CTFont and CTFontDescriptor, are even TFB with their Cocoa counterparts.